# C# DocumentFormat.OpenXML: Applying StyleRef to paragraph doesn't work

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I'm editing a word document in C# using DocumentFormat.OpenXML. I want to replace text and apply a heading style. Finding and replacing text works fine, but the style reference won't work. What I'm doing so far:

```
int chapterNo = 1;
// Last step of opening the document
Body body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
// Iterate throug all paragraphs containing a given text
foreach(Paragraph p in body.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where<Paragraph>(p => p.InnerText.Contains("**")))
{
    // Remove text and styles
    p.RemoveAllChildren<Run>();
    p.RemoveAllChildren<ParagraphProperties>();
    // Append new style to paragraph
    p.PrependChild<ParagraphProperties>(new ParagraphProperties(new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "heading 1" }));
    // Add new text to paragraph
    p.AppendChild<Run>(new Run(new Text($"Chapter {chapterNo}")));
    chapterNo++;
}
```

Everything seems to work except for the style. The new text shows in the document, but it is formatted as standard text, not as header 1 as intended. I already tried different names for the style reference ("Header 1", "Header1", "header 1", "header1", and, as I'm in Germany, "Überschrift 1"). How can I apply the style to the paragraph? It's important that not only the text looks like a header but a table of content can be created using the style references.

Comment: Are you sure that the "heading 1" is the right value? Check the "styles.xml" part in your DOCX file, is there any mention of `w:styleId="heading 1"`? I'm guessing that you'll find the `w:styleId="Heading1"` instead so try changing the value to "Heading1". Does that work for you?

Comment: I checked styles.xml twice, and I tried several values beside the one I found there. But I'll check again later that day.

Comment: If you're still experiencing an issue, can you upload somewhere your DOCX file so that I can take a look at it?

Comment: Got it! "berschrift2" did the trick. Apparantly the German Word edition can't handle the English styleId, but on the other hand it can't handle the German char "Ü" as well, so "Überschrift" (German word for "title" or "heading") becomes "berschrift". For some reason, perhaps due to the template I'm using, the upmost heading level is unknown, too, but that's fine with me, I need just one level.